# JavaFX Binding Setter Convention

Tags: binding, javafx, javabeans

I know Java and C#, but property binding I only know from C# MVVM.
I am trying to understand property binding in JavaFX with custom getters and setters for property values (like in C#).

I have created the following classes:

```
public class ViewModel {

    private StringProperty name;

    public ViewModel() {
        name = new SimpleStringProperty();
    }

    public final String getName() {
        return name.get();
    }

    public final void setName(String name) {
        this.name.set(name);
    }

    public StringProperty getNameProperty() {
        return name;
    }
}

public class Controller implements Initializable {

    @FXML
    private TextField nameField;

    private final ViewModel viewModel;

    public Controller() {
        viewModel = new ViewModel();
    }

    @Override
    public void initialize(URL url, ResourceBundle resourceBundle) {
        Bindings.bindBidirectional(nameField.textProperty(),
                viewModel.getNameProperty());
    }
}
```

I was under impression that if I follow the recommended JavaBean/JavaFX naming convention, then the binding system will be clever enough to use reflection(?) and use my custom getter / setter for the property. But my view model getter / setter is never used.

Instead, the binding uses properties' get/set methods directly without my interaction.
I read that I can use the following code, but there has to be a better way than this:

```
name = new SimpleStringProperty() {
    @Override public void set(String value) {
        // do something...
        super.set(value);
    }
};
```

Can I specify which methods the bindings should use to get / set my properties?
And on a side note, how can I notify that the property has changed (NotifyOfPropertyChange() in C#) without having to change it?

**EDIT:**

What I am trying to do is a bit more selective as to what ends up being set to my Property, since I'd like to use it's value later on to populate my data model (omitted here).

In C# this is trivial, I just set a predicate in the setter. And I can drive the progress of a form / wizard by just setting other properties along the way.

```
public String Property {
    get { return _property; }
    set { 
        if(SomePredicate(value)) {
            _property = value;
            _nextButtonCommand.canExecute() = true;
            // notify...
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: Updated answer in response to edit.

Comment: I actually like overriding the property set. For some reason in my code, when I do it like the answer below, the setter never gets called. I am doing my whole application  with only FXML and my model with my controller having no code behind though.

Answer (score 4):

**JavaFX Properties**

The convention for defining a `name` property in your `ViewModel` class is:

```
public class ViewModel {

    private StringProperty name;

    public ViewModel() {
        // parameters are owning bean, property name, and initial value, 
        // and are optional for the property convention
        name = new SimpleStringProperty(this, "name", "");
    }

    public final String getName() {
        return name.get();
    }

    public final void setName(String name) {
        this.name.set(name);
    }

    // Note this method name:
    public final StringProperty nameProperty() {
        return name;
    }
}
```

There are some variants: in particular if you want to make things overridable, you can remove the `final` modifier from `nameProperty()` and replace `this.name` with `this.nameProperty()` in the get and set methods. The key point is to ensure that calling `setName(...)` always gives the same result as `nameProperty().set(...)` (and similarly for the get methods).

I think your general interpretation is somehow off by one level (if that makes sense). The [`StringProperty`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/javafx/api/javafx/beans/property/StringProperty.html) class defines `get` and `set` methods, and those are the methods that will be "automatically" invoked for you because of your binding. So (even though you have a slightly non-standard naming convention), typing in the text field will still update the property value. The binding API doesn't use (much?) reflection, as far as I am aware - it simply registers listeners with the properties and updates one when another changes.

As for custom getters and setters, those are really only supported for the property classes by the overriding technique you showed. I've never really found a good use case for those, though, especially with the bindings API, which gives you the opportunity to create dependent values quite easily.

**Update**

So for your specific example, I would implement it along the following lines:

```
public class ViewModel {
    private StringProperty name = new SimpleStringProperty(this, "name");
    // usual JavaFX Property methods...
}
```

Then, wherever you need it:

```
Predicate<String> predicate = ... ;
BooleanBinding canExecute = Bindings.createBooleanBinding(() -> 
    predicate.test(viewModel.getName()),
    viewModel.nameProperty());
```

and then you can do things like

```
Button nextButton = new Button("Next");
nextButton.disableProperty().bind(canExecute.not());
```

If the predicate might change, you can even do

```
ObjectProperty<Predicate<String>> predicate = new SimpleObjectProperty<>(s -> true);
BooleanBinding canExecute = Bindings.createBooleanBinding(() -> 
    predicate.get().test(viewModel.getName()),
    predicate, viewModel.nameProperty());
```

There are many, many factory methods in the [`Bindings` class](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/javafx/api/javafx/beans/binding/Bindings.html) for creating bindings, and you can also subclass the abstract `ObjectBinding`, `StringBinding`, etc classes if needed.

Note there is a subtle change in philosophy between this approach and the one suggested in the question: in the approach in the question (subclassing `SimpleStringProperty`), the logic for determining if the action is executable is held by the string property. In this approach it is factored out into a different object which observes the string property (via the binding, which actually registers a [`WeakInvalidationListener`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/javafx/api/javafx/beans/WeakInvalidationListener.html) on the string property).

**Notification**

You can register [`InvalidationListener`s](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/javafx/api/javafx/beans/InvalidationListener.html) or [`ChangeListener`s](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/javafx/api/javafx/beans/value/ChangeListener.html) with a property. The `addListener(InvalidationListener)` method is inherited from [`Observable`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/javafx/api/javafx/beans/Observable.html), and indicates that the value last observed may no longer be valid. This allows for "lazy evaluating" observables, which only compute a new value when it's requested. The `addListener(ChangeListener)` method is inherited from [`ObservableValue`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/javafx/api/javafx/beans/value/ObservableValue.html), which (as its name indicates) is an observable that explicitly wraps a value. Registering a `ChangeListener` forces eager evaluation, as the listener is notified with the new value. The API is a little too fine-grained for my taste, though it does provide lots and lots of flexibility for high-performing implementations.

So in your test app, you can do

```
viewModel.nameProperty().addListener(new ChangeListener<String>() {
    @Override
    public void changed(ObservableValue<? extends String> obs, String oldValue, String newValue) {
        System.out.println("Name changed from "+oldValue+" to "+newValue);
    }
});
```

or, in Java 8, the vastly more succinct

```
viewModel.nameProperty().addListener((obs, oldName, newName) -> 
    System.out.println("Name changed from "+oldValue+" to "+newValue));
```

The difference between invalidation listeners and change listeners only becomes apparent if you have an `ObservableValue` that depends on a computation. Compare:

```
IntegerProperty x = new SimpleIntegerProperty(2);
IntegerProperty y = new SimpleIntegerProperty(3);
ObservableNumberValue sum = x.add(y);

sum.addListener(obs -> System.out.println("Invalidated")); // invalidation listener
x.set(3);
y.set(5);
```

with the same code, but with the change listener:

```
sum.addListener((obs, oldSum, newSum) -> System.out.println("Changed"));
```

instead of the invalidation listener.

There are more details in the [tutorial](http://www.oracle.com/pls/topic/lookup?ctx=javase80&id=JFXBD107).